# How can I make tdb2.xloader continue loading when the loading accidentally interrupt?

Tags: jena, tdb

Apache Version
4.8.0

Question
This afternoon I was using tdb2.xloader to load a 120G ttl file into the database, but it was accidentally interrupted halfway, but the loading has reached the POS stage, Is there any chance I can continue building on the basis of what has already been built? It takes me seven hours to built this database, I would be appreciate if this seven hours is not wasted.
The command I use to load the ttl file is

```
tdb2.xloader --loc /xxx --threads 100 xxx.ttl
```

Here is the directory of things that have been built.
[image]
[image]

I refer to the official docs on the Jena website, but I don't find concerning solutions. But It seems to be a phase loader by default. So I wander whether it cound continue to build on phase have been built.

Comment: Duplicate of question : https://github.com/apache/jena/issues/1951

Comment: Oh, That's a issue published by myself. And the question had been answered @AndyS

Comment: Indeed! The comment is a trail for everyone else.

Comment: Oh, I am newbie here, glad to know that. @AndyS